# Where did WebJob ServiceBusTrigger disappear?

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus, azure-webjobs

I have a WebJob that parses a ServiceBus Topic Subscription.

Now I read several examples of using the WebJob binding mechanism to make the code cleaner.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/ServiceBus/Functions.cs
http://blog.devscrum.net/2014/09/using-azure-web-jobs-simplify-running-background-processes/
http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/sspencer/post/2014/07/03/Creating-a-Simple-Workflow-with-Azure-Webjobs-and-Service-Bus.aspx

So I downloaded the following in Nuget:

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 1.0.0

Windows.Azure.Storage 4.3.0

Namespaces look fine. QueueTrigger is there. But the ServiceBusTrigger is nowhere to be found!
Is that binding suddenly removed from the scope?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's in  a [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/):

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus
```

Comment: Thanks, that made the difference :)